# Match file name with glob function

Tags: php, glob

I have the following filenames:

```
foo.ext
foo-1.ext
foo-2.ext
foo-3.ext
```

Currently the code

```
$name = "foo-[0-9].*";
glob($name as a $filename){
    echo $filename;
}
```

Only matches

```
foo1-ext
foo2-ext
foo3-ext
```

But no foo.ext

How do I modify my glob to also match that?

Comment: I have removed the `regex` tag and replaced it with the `globbing` tag. There is a big difference between the two. Look it up.

Comment: Have a look at the [Wikipedia article on glob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29) for more help.

Comment: First glob with foo* and then, second, filter the results with a regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is **NOT** a regex, this is globbing.

There is a huge difference between the two.

Globbing is the use of wildcard characters as used when you specify files on the command line.

So in globbing, the expression `foo*` means 'foo' followed by **ANY** (or no) characters.

Whereas, in regex, the expression `foo*` means 'fo' following any number (including zero occurences) of the 'o' character.

Globbing is much more restrictive than regex.

About the only way to get what you want is `"foo*.*"`.

Comment: "This is NOT a regex, this is globbing." getting t-shirt printed with that on it

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
$name = "foo(-[0-9])?.*";
```

It's something along those lines anyway!

Comment: Although the OP has incorrectly tagged this question with `regex`, the expression he is using is a globbing expression, not a regex. There is a huge difference.